# c# - program not exiting

Tags: c#, exit

just started using C#, and this may be just a simple fix but I can't seem to see it.  Once the program executes the first time (after adding two numbers), the user is prompted to input yes or no as an exit condition.  When I type in 'no', the program will loop again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool again = false;
            while (!again)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C# Basic Calcuator");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers to be added: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");

                int result;
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Result: ");
                result = a + b;

                //print result
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                //potential exit condition
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to calculate again?");
                if(Console.ReadLine() == "no")
                {
                    again = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    again = true;
                }

            }



        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to change the condition (no==true)?

Comment: hint: what happens if you type 'yes' instead of 'no'?

Comment: Not answer but if you want the loop to run at least once, you should change it to a Do..While loop instead.

Comment: Use tolower() and trim() and put break points to debug the value of the again and see where is it problem

Comment: You could also learn about the break keyword.

Comment: Another comment that may or may not be worth considering. You might want to check for `NO` in addition to `no`, as well as `No` and `nO`. This can be easily done by using a [case insensitive string comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the top 2 lines to the following:

```
bool again = true;
while (again)
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
while (!again)
```

with

```
while (again)
```

when user types no, `again` is set to false; so in the `while` loop again is negated which results in continuation of while loop.

by the way, you need to change

```
bool again = false;
```

to

```
bool again = true;
```

Comment: Then it won't do the loop at all :p

Comment: Making this change doesn't allow the program to begin execution.

Comment: @xtheking: No, program execution begins, just the body of the loop doesn't execute. But yeah, just set the initial value of `again` to `true`.

Comment: This is the perfect occasion to use `do...while` instead of `while`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want with use of `While` with making minor changes as suggested by differnet people here but You can even Use `do while` instead of while which will go in loop first time and then will check for the condition everytime:-

As MSDN says :-

> The do statement executes a statement or a block of statements
>   repeatedly until a specified expression evaluates to false. The body
>   of the loop must be enclosed in braces, {}, unless it consists of a
>   single statement. In that case, the braces are optional.

```
bool again = false;
               do {
                Console.WriteLine("C# Basic Calcuator");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter two numbers to be added: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");

                int result;
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Result: ");
                result = a + b;

                //print result
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                //potential exit condition
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to calculate again?");
                if(Console.ReadLine() == "no")
                {
                    again = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    again = true;
                }

            }  while (again);
```

Comment: You still have the same problem the original code had. `!false == true`

Comment: sorry it was typo @GrantWinney

Comment: Also, using a `Do...While` maybe better style for this particular loop, but it's not necessary. The original loop does just fine if they fix the problem with the condition.

Comment: yes agree @MattBurland I have just given one option coz rest of the answers were already given

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
again = (Console.ReadLine() == "no" ? true : false);
```

But your choice of variable naming is really ambiguous, a better name could be

```
bool stopLoop = false;
while (!stopLoop)
{
    .....
    stopLoop = (Console.ReadLine() == "no" ? true : false);
}
```

As pointed in the comment below, you shouldn't try to convert to an integer what your user types without a better check for errors. Using Convert.ToInt32 on a non numeric value throws an exception. A better code could be

```
  int result;
  if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
       continue;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe include in your answer the exceptions it will throw if say "yes" is added for either one of the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Accidental programming powers activate!

```
if(Console.ReadLine() == "no")
    again = true;
else
    again = false;
```

And also you might wanna want to change the name of the variable to something like `stop_flag` so that it would make sense.

Comment: again = Console.ReadLine() == "no"; <- economize some lines

Comment: Yeah, added this moment to my answer.